# How to align two <a/> to the center using flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Below are my html and css code.

```css
.tab {
  display: flex;
  self-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.section-title {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
}
.label {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}
.label-a {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
.label-b {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class=tab>
  <a class=section-title>
    <div class="label label-a">Tab a</div>
  </a>
  <a class=section-title>
    <div class="label label-b">Tab b</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Currently it gives the following result:
[image]

My goal is to make the green and orange boxes to move to the center of the red bordered box, like so:

[image]

I have tried a few things such as:

1) Use `margin: auto`

2) Make sure `.tab` width is 100%.

3) `.section-title` and `.label` use flexbox in `display` property

Why the alignment does not work as I expect? Is it because `a` is not a block element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add justify-content: center to your .tab class:

```
.tab {
   display: flex;
   self-align: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin: auto;
   width: 100%;
   justify-content: center;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply plain `text-align: center`?

```css
.tab {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.section-title {
  margin: 5px;
}
.label {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.label-a {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
.label-b {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class=tab>
  <a class=section-title>
    <div class="label label-a">Tab a</div>
  </a>
  <a class=section-title>
    <div class="label label-b">Tab b</div>
  </a>
</div>
```